# Windows command: "net user <name> <password>" does not work

Tags: windows-7, passwords

I forgot my user account Windows 7 Pro password and I am trying to reset it.

I don't have a reset password disk, unfortunately.

I did manage to obtain an admin cmd prompt, where I type:

> net user

Windows says the command completed successfully, but

after I reboot, my new password still does not work.

I also tried

> net user  /passwordreq:no

again, completed successfully, and after reboot, still can't log in without a password.

Why doesn't "net user" work?

I can use

> net user /add foobar

to get a new user and log in, so that means I do have a successful admin account prompt.  Somehow it is only

> net user

password functionality that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

OK that is really weird.  Normally, to get

> net user /add foobar

and other such commands, to work, I have to reboot the machine.

However, in the case of net user password functionality, it only works if I *do* *not* reboot the machine.